# Connect to SQL Server 2000 without installing connectivity tools

Tags: sql-server-2000, remote-connection

I am using 2 machines.

1. Windows server 2003 with SQL Server 2005 (default instance) `MySrvName`" and with SQL Server 2000 (named instance) `MySrvName\SQL2000`
2. Windows 7 with VS 2010
3. LAN (works fine)

When I connect to SQL Server 2005 it works fine from win7 and win 2003 but when I try to connect to SQL Server 2000 via win7 it says

> *The server was not found or was not accessible*

This instance (`SQL2000`) is working fine from Windows server machine. I have tried disabling all firewalls (default of windows).

In 2002-3 I used to have same issue which I used to resolve by installing MSDE/connectivity tools. Is there a way to resolve without installing anything? Or any single file to install these connectivity tools from?

Comment: I just found on following location that we have to install connectivity tools. But is there a single file link for that?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176563(v=SQL.80).aspx